# Jmeter: How to run multiple instances on single server in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load, load-testing

I'm trying to run a test plan in Jmeter which has multiple scripts and each script is pointing to each instances and respective databases.

```
Test plan1:
Script 1: Test1
Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://10.30.1.59;instanceName=INSTANCE01;Database=DB1
Script 2:Test2
Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://10.30.1.59;instanceName=INSTANCE02;Database=DB2
```

But the script creates a record only in one instance not in the other instance.
How do i achieve this ?

Note: SQL server 2022
Two instances- Instance01 and Instance02
Databases: DB1 and DB2

Things i tried and failed:

1. Tried giving port numbers in Database URL
   2.Configured separate TCP/IP port numbers(1433 and 1434) for each instance in Server configuration manager.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have 2 separate [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) elements which have separate JDBC URLs pointing to different instances and defining different [connection pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool):

[image]

if you run JDBC Sampler twice using different pool values:

[image]

the query should run against different instances

If SQL query fails somewhere somehow it should be reflected in the Sample Result, check if the correct URL is used and how many rows are updated by the query using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

It also worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries, a good idea would be [enabling debug logging for JMeter JDBC test elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc" level="debug" />
```